# How to create new tasks in Microsoft Project Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

We are using Microsoft Project Server 2013 within Microsoft SharePoint 2013. Is it possible to create a Task in a Project for example from a WebPart via C# in CodeBehind?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do a Webpart to create tasks but, via CSOM you can connect to your PS2013 Projects and create some tasks.

I will post you here a piece of code that could help you:

You must first "Check-Out" the project like this:

```
projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
projContext.ExecuteQuery();

var proj = projContext.Projects.First(p => p.Name == "Project");
projContext.ExecuteQuery();

var draftProj = proj.CheckOut();

projContext.Load(draftProj.Tasks);
projContext.ExecuteQuery();

CreateNewTask(draftProj);
```

Then, you can call the method of create new task sending the "draft project"

```
private static void CreateNewTask(DraftProject draftProj)
{
    TaskCreationInformation nt = new TaskCreationInformation();

    nt.Name = "Task name";
    nt.Start = DateTime.Today;
    nt.Duration = "20d";
    nt.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    draftProj.Tasks.Add(nt);
    projContext.Load(draftProj.Tasks);

    draftProj.Update();
    projContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the post. But the problem is the user authorization. I mean this code works fine when using SharePoint Online/PWA Online or using from a Console Application. But it does not work when you execute it from a "artefact" within SharePoint. Cause the Project Context is always executed by the IIS User/App Pool Account. Within Project Online you can use a Token for the user and execute within the users context. But that is not possible within OnPremise SharePoint. And Username/Password is not an option. No user would type in credentials (again) within enterprise SSO environment.

Comment: Hi Storm, I'm so sorry hearing that and also sorry for not helping you and missunderstood what you was asking for. Well, if I find some solution to your problem, don't doubt I will post it here. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem. Thanks trying helping me.

Comment: @STORM There is a javascript CSOM -- that, I believe, uses the user's current session -- You could probably build a webpart that uses that API. -- We definitely use the SharePoint version of that API in web apps that run inside of SharePoint.

Comment: @MarcLluis -- is it not necessary to Wait for the `QueueJob` returned by the `.Update` call? -- and is it not necessary to call `draftProj.CheckIn` afterwards? (Like does it leave the project in a weird "checked out" state?)

Comment: @BrainSlug: We have tested this but the "authorization" worked only within the PWA sitecollection not within "normal" sitecollection outsite pwa. There we had to provide user credentials. Is this also your experience?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 -- Yep, there some missing things because of I resume the answer but you are in truth, you need to call `.Update` and also `.CheckIn` to set in the "current" status that you could spect to find a project as a Project Manager

Comment: its return this error "CICOCheckedOutInOtherSession" while executing check out